# Java inheritance TextArea

Tags: java, class, inheritance, textarea, instance

I am unsure if I can inherit the instance of a textArea in one class and add text to it from another class. I have simplified my code below to stay focused. In main.java the TextArea box is created and text is added with an append. I want to in another class inputclass.java, add another append to the same instance of the textArea so the TextArea should read
Hello
Bye

main.java

```
package NineNetwork;

public class TextMessage extends JFrame  {
     public TextMessage() {
         private JTextArea WinMessage = new JTextArea(20,25);
         WinMessage.append("Hello" + "\n");
     }
}
```

inputClass.java

```
package NineNetwork;

public class inputClass  {
     public inputClass() {
         WinMessage.append("Bye" + "\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: "*I have simplified my code below to stay focused.*" that is good, but that simplification added problem which prevent us from staying focused. That problem is that local variables don't have visibility modifiers. Only class fields do.

Answer (score 0):

Without know much about your project, I think you are going to have a hard time with accomplishing this task if you create the WinMessage variable within your TextMessage constructor. I am assuming it is not absolutely vital that the variable is created in the constructor. So, I would suggest using some sort of setter method like so:

```
package NineNetwork;

public class TextMessage extends JFrame  {
    private JTextArea WinMessage = new JTextArea(20,25);

    public TextMessage() {
        WinMessage.append("Hello" + "\n");
    }

    public void appendMessage(String text){
        WinMessage.append(text);
    }

}
```

And then you could access it like so:

```
 package NineNetwork;

 public class inputClass  {
     public inputClass() {
          TextMessage.appendMessage("Bye" + "\n");
     }
 }
```

This should make you text field have an output of

> Hello
>
> Bye

When you call the method.